# WebAPI 2 Create Custom Authentication Token

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I want to create Custom Bearer Token, with some additional information to be store in the token.

*Just want to Use Create Token functionality.(something like FormsAuthentication) without using default implementation(ASP.NET Identity) of User Tables.*

1) Custom Login method(MyLogin), that will create custom bearer token with additional information(IP Address embedded into token).
2) on subsequent request be able to inspect the additional information and reject(treat the request as unauthenticated) if the additional information does not match some rule. 
 In case i receive the bearer token and find the request is coming from different IP address then the one embedded inside it, clear/Invalidate the Bearer Token and treat the current request as UnAuthenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert but this is the information i gathered.

This seems to be relatively simple to do with ASP.NET Identity.

You need to create your own implementation of a token provider which implements the [IAuthenticationTokenProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.infrastructure.iauthenticationtokenprovider%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) interface. You implement the create method so it creates the token just the way you want and then you supply your provider when configuring the authentication middleware.

The configuration in your starup class would look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
    //Rest of code is here;
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/yourtokenendpoint"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            AccessTokenProvider = new YourCustomTokenProvider() // YourCustomTokenProvider implements IAuthenticationTokenProvider 
        };

        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions bearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AccessTokenProvider = new YourCustomTokenProvider() // YourCustomTokenProvider implements IAuthenticationTokenProvider 
        }


        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearerOptions);

    }
}
```

I have never done this myself but I hope this was of some use.

EDIT: To validate the the token you could create a custom action filter that you decorate your controller actions with. In this action filter you could validate the token and do whatever you like with the request. See [this guide](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=976).